# ¿Como saber si un año es bisiesto?

Tags: c#, año-bisiesto

## **Esta pregunta es autorespondida.**

Esta pregunta parece sencilla, pero no lo es, ya que hay muchas personas que no la responden bien, ya que para el calendario gregoriano los bisiestos se calculan de manera diferente al calendario juliano.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## **Un poco de historia:**

Originalmente, el calendario que se utilizaba en Roma(que dio origen al actual), no
se regía por el movimiento del sol, y consistía en **300** **días** divididos en **10** **meses** de
**30** **días**. Este calendario no era adecuado para administrar la agricultura, pues no
facilitaba interpretar los ciclos de siembra y cosecha que acompañan a las estaciones
y al sol en sus movimientos. Es por ello que, después de mucho tiempo, cambios y
ajustes, se estableció en la época de **Julio César** el **calendario juliano**, que constaba
de **365.25 días**, o sea cada año era de **365 + 0.25 días**, por lo que se establecieron
los años de **365 días** más un día adicional cada **4 años** para recuperar la
acumulación de la fracción de **0.25 días**. Sin embargo, luego se determinó que una
medición más exacta resulta del año solar y era la de **365.2425 días**, de modo que
cada **4 años** no se acumula exactamente un día sino **0.97 días**. Es por ello
que el **4 de octubre de 1582** se desplazó al año oficial en **10 días** con respecto al año
solar, y el **papa Gregorio XIII** decretó que el día siguiente sería el **15 de octubre de
1582**. Además, para corregir el error se implantó entonces el **calendario gregoriano**:
los años serán de **365 días** y cada **4 años** se agregará un día al mes de febrero,
tal como en el **calendario juliano(año bisiesto)**, pero para corregir el error, cada
**25** veces de tales años bisiestos de **366 días**(o sea cada **100 años**) el año será de
**365 días**, a menos que ese año sea a la vez un múltiplo de **400**. Si se hace el cálculo:
**1/4 - 1/100 + 1/400 = 0.2425** da exactamente el error que se acumula por cada año
de **365 días**. Luego para verificar que un año es bisiesto(es decir con **29 días** en
febrero, en lugar de **28**), hay que comprobar que sea divisible por **4**, pero no puede ser
divisible por **100**, a menos que lo sea por **400**.

Por tanto hay que tener en cuenta que antes del **año** **1582** los años bisiestos se calculan de manera diferente a los años bisiestos posteriores a **1582** (Aquí no se tiene en cuenta la **norma ISO 8601**, más adelante me refiero a ella):

```
private bool EsBisiesto(int anno)
{
    if(anno < 1582)
    {
        if(anno % 4 == 0) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if((anno % 400 == 0) || ((anno % 4 == 0) && !(anno % 100 == 0)))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Lo primero que se hace en este algoritmo es preguntar si el año es anterior al **año** **1582**, ya que hasta ese momento se utilizaba el **calendario juliano**, de cumplirse esta condición se hace el cálculo correspondiente a los años bisiestos previo al **año** **1582**. De no cumplirse esta condición, es decir el año es posterior o igual a **1582**, entonces el cálculo se haría como se establece en el **calendario gregoriano**.

**Bibliografía:**

**Título:** Empezar a programar. Un enfoque multiparadigma con C#.

**Autor:** Miguel Katrib Mora.

**ISBN:** 978-959-7251-25-5

## **Actualización:**

Después de un interesante debate con @Yussef y viendo que por convención (**norma ISO 8601**) se decidió para evitar complejidades en el manejo de fechas tratar las fechas del **calendario juliano** como si se tratasen de fechas del **calendario gregoriano**, algo conocido como **calendario gregoriano proléptico**, el algoritmo aceptado para ver si un año es bisiesto es:

```
private static bool EsBisiesto(int anno)
{
    return (anno % 400 == 0) || (anno % 4 == 0 && anno % 100 != 0);
}
```

Además, **C#** tiene una función propia para esto que es la **función IsLeapYear**:

```
bool bisiesto = DateTime.IsLeapYear(anno);
```

## **Actualización 2**:

**C#** también permite determinar si un año es bisiesto en el **calendario Juliano**, para ello debe hacer uso de la **clase JulianCalendar** y su **método IsLeapYear**:

```
JulianCalendar jc = new JulianCalendar();
bool esBisiesto = jc.IsLeapYear(anno);
```

Comment: Maravilla de explicación. Te luciste con todo, hasta los datos y la referencia bibliográfica. Gracias bro :D

Answer (score 3):

C# cuenta con la función `DateTime.IsLeapYear(int)` que retorna si un año es bisiesto o no

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.IsLeapYear(2000)); //True 
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.IsLeapYear(2001)); //False
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.IsLeapYear(2004)); //True
```

Unas aclaraciones:

El año solar tiene 365,2422 días, por lo que el calendario Gregoriano se adelanta 6 segundos por año, y en algún punto en el futuro vamos a tener que reajustarlo

Luego cuando uno está en un sistema numérico o calendario, no es recomendable cambiar la regla de medición a mitad de camino, por esto las fechas anteriores a 1582 se convierten a `Calendario gregoriano proléptico` y esto está en la norma `ISO 8601` que ve las cuestiones de las fechas.

Es decir, por norma, aunque contemos años anteriores al 1582, lo seguimos haciendo en calendario gregoriano.

Esto produce una diferencia para esos años entre el algoritmo del OP y la función `IsLeapYear`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.IsLeapYear(1000)); // False
    Console.WriteLine(EsBisiesto(1000)); //True
}
private static bool EsBisiesto(int anno)
{
    if (anno < 1582) return anno % 4 == 0;
    return (anno % 400 == 0) || (anno % 4 == 0 && anno % 100 != 0);
}
```

Comment: El calendario gregoriano proleptico se creo para evitar complejidades en el manejo de fechas, digamos que fue un pie forzado de la humanidad para no complicarnos la vida, pero la forma correcta es hacer los cálculos atendiendo a cada calendario,  sería más exacto, la humanidad se inventa métodos para no complicarse, 1 día tiene 23h 56min, no 24 horas, pero es más fácil llevarlo a 24horas como mismo es más fácil decir que la velocidad de la luz es 300 000 km/s cuando es aproximadamente 270 000 km/s

Comment: Ve mi respuesta como una curiosidad, como un interesante ejercicio académico y si puedes consigue el libro

Comment: @Japv No es así, son calendarios distintos. El juliano no termina en el 1582 sino que contempla hasta la fecha actual, así como tampoco el gregoriano no comienza en 1582.  Cosa distinta es que su aplicación o uso comience en X fecha. No puedes ir contando días en gregoriano y a mitad de camino pasarse a juliano, es como ir contando en kilometros y a la mitad pasarse a millas. Porque además distintos países aplicaron el gregoriano en años distintos, para Inglaterra no fue hasta el 1752, o sea que habría que incluir el país en el algoritmo

Comment: @Japv Lo entiendo, ve mi respuesta como un complemento a la tuya

Answer (score 1):

En PHP no existe algo nativo dentro de las clases que manejan fechas por lo tanto tambien nos vemos en la necesidad de implementar el siguiente script:

```
function esBisiesto($anio) {
    if ($anio < 1582) {
        // Aproximación para años anteriores a 1582
        return $anio % 4 === 0;
    } else {
        // Reglas estándar del calendario gregoriano para años a partir de 1582
        return ($anio % 4 === 0 && ($anio % 100 !== 0 || $anio % 400 === 0));
    }
}

// Ejemplo de uso:
$anio = 1500;

if (esBisiesto($anio)) {
    echo $anio . " es un año bisiesto.";
} else {
    echo $anio . " no es un año bisiesto.";
}
```